# Mask a string with dashes in PHP

Tags: php, replace

I have the following string:

```
$thetextstring = "jjfnj 948"
```

At the end I want to have:

```
echo $thetextstring; // should print jjf-nj948
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to remove the spaces from the string then separate the first 3 letters from the rest of the string with a `-`.

So far I have

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/s+/', ' ', $thetextstring));

$result =  explode(" ", $thetextstring);

$newstring = implode('', $result);

print_r($newstring);
```

I have been able to join the words, but how do I add the separator after the first 3 letters?

Comment: If any answers on StackOverflow helped you, please mark them as accepted. It's not only about this question, it's about all your questions. Let's be responsible to other visitors and indicate what actually solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oldschool without regex

```
$test = "jjfnj 948";
$test = str_replace(" ", "", $test);  // strip all spaces from string
echo substr($test, 0, 3)."-".substr($test, 3);  // isolate first three chars, add hyphen, and concat all characters after the first three
```

Comment: Doing `substr` on one string twice in this context is bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex with `preg_replace` function, this would be a one-liner:

```
^.{3}\K([^\s]*) *
```

Breakdown:

```
^   # Assert start of string
.{3}    # Match 3 characters
\K  # Reset match
([^\s]*) * # Capture everything up to space character(s) then try to match them
```

PHP code:

```
echo preg_replace('~^.{3}\K([^\s]*) *~', '-$1', 'jjfnj 948');
```

**[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/hAeck)**

Comment: The first step is on how do i split the current word to jjfnj 948, currently my word is att jjfnj948?

Comment: You didn't talk about this in your question. Did you? @GEOFFREYMWANGI

Comment: So you have `jjfnj948` and want to have `jjf-nj948`? @GEOFFREYMWANGI

Comment: I completely agree with you. But for a guy, who has no idea of what he's doing (I mean OP, just read his comments), the best would be the easiest. This answer he would probably mindlessly copy and will think, that SO will answer all his questions anytime anywhere.

Comment: I did go through a breakdown to shed some light on regex itself. Besides I'm open to questions if there are any. @AlexKarshin

Comment: Yes, indeed. But you're missing my point. Nevertheless, let's not continue this philosophical discussion. Here, have a +1 from me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$thetextstring = "jjfnj 948";

// replace all spaces with nothing
$thetextstring = str_replace(" ", "", $thetextstring);

// insert a dash after the third character
$thetextstring = substr_replace($thetextstring, "-", 3, 0);

echo $thetextstring;
```

This gives the requested `jjf-nj948`

Comment: The first step is on how do i split the current word to jjfnj 948, currently my word is att jjfnj948?

Comment: You already have `$thetextstring = "jjfnj 948"`, read your own question again.

Comment: Good, clean non-regex answer.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI If you liked Stv's answer, then you should LOVE Alex's answer because it performs with 1 fewer function calls (which means it is clean, direct, and uses the most appropriate function calls).  I would encourage you to accept this answer if you are seeking a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about how your strings can vary, this is working solution for your task:

Pattern:

```
~([a-z]{2}) ~  // 2 letters (contained in capture group1) followed by a space
```

Replace:

```
-$1
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/3rdi3G/1)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dTa47))

```
$thetextstring = "jjfnj 948";
echo preg_replace('~([a-z]{2}) ~','-$1',$thetextstring);
```

Output:

```
jjf-nj948
```

**Note** this pattern can easily be expanded to include characters beyond lowercase letters that precede the space.  `~(\S{2}) ~`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` to remove the unwanted space:

```
$newString = str_replace(' ', '', $thetextstring);
```

$newString:

```
jjfnj948
```

And then `preg_replace` to put in the dash:

```
$final = preg_replace('/^([a-z]{3})/', '\1-', $newString);
```

The meaning of this regex instruction is:

- from the beginning of the line: `^`
- capture three a-z characters: `([a-z]{3})`
- replace this match with itself followed by a dash: `\1-`

$final:

```
jjf-nj948
```

Comment: Calling `str_replace()` before `preg_replace()` indicates a sub-optimal regex pattern has been written.  This answer is not best practice.

Comment: Trying not to assume the input format will always be the same.

Comment: As Alex, revo, and I have proven, this task can and should be completed directly by using either 1 `preg_replace()` call or 2 non-regex function calls.  Anything more or different would be less direct and/or sub-optimal.

Comment: You've proven nothing. Your solution breaks as soon as the space moves or if there is more than one.

Comment: That is for the OP to clarify in the question.

Comment: It is best to build resilient solutions that are easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

You proceeding is correct. For the last step, which consists in inserting a `-` after the third character, you can use the [substr_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) as follows:

```
$thetextstring = 'jjfnj 948';  
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $thetextstring));
$result = explode(' ', $thetextstring);
$newstring = substr_replace(implode('', $result), '-', 3, false);
```

If you are confident enough that your string will always have the same format (characters followed by a whitespace followed by numbers), you can also reduce your computations and simplify your code as follows:

```
$thetextstring = 'jjfnj 948';  
$newstring = substr_replace(str_replace(' ', '', $thetextstring), '-', 3, false);
```

Visit [this link](https://eval.in/958537) for a working demo.

Comment: The OP doesn't have multiple spaces that need to be reduced to one space.  That portion of this answer is needless.  Also, generating a temporary array from exploding on the space only to re-implode is not direct programming.  Calling `substr_replace()` is a good idea, but using `false` as  the final parameter will cause issues in PHP7.  Here is how your answer _could_ look: https://3v4l.org/5tirE